# Restore Web Application issue

Tags: powershell, authentication, web-application, restore

I am using PowerShell to restore a SP Web Application on the same farm. I am following the below TechNet article. It says "When you restore a web application that is configured to use claims-based authentication, there are additional steps that you must follow after restoring the web application to restore claims-based authentication."

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748647.aspx

I am not sure of the steps though. By default, all web applications in 2013 are configured for Claims-Based Authentication. My web application was using Windows authentication. After the restore, when I try to hit the URL of the site, I get the page with a drop down to choose the authentication. Interestingly, it only shows Windows Authentication in the drop down. This is not the expected behavior. Before the restore, it was prompting directly for Windows credentials and not this page. Has anyone ever encountered this? If so, can anyone please shed some light? This is weird. Unfortunately, the above link doesn't even have any examples for the restore operation. Note: I want a PowerShell based solution.

Comment: I think you're confusing your terms.  Windows authentication refers to either NTLM or Kerberos.  This is completely separate from the Classic vs Claims configuration as you can have any combination of each.  How did you restore your Web Application (note, this is different to restoring a site collection)?

Comment: I don't think I am confused. Claims comes in 3 flavors. Windows, Forms and Trusted Provider. NTLM and Kerberos are within Windows. I restored the web application using PS command provided in the TechNet link.

Comment: A Web Application can be in one of two modes, Classic or Claims, regardless of whether you're using Windows, Forms or SAML.  Have a read of https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx.   What do you see when you run the following command:  Get-SPWebApplication |select Name, UseClaimsAuthentication ?

Comment: Sorry to reiterate. Those are modes, but Claims can be Windows, Forms or Trusted Identity claims. It is clearly called out in the link that you provided above. "Windows accounts are converted into Windows claims. Forms-based membership users are transformed into forms-based authentication claims." Anyway, it returns True for all the web applications in my farm.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity <URL>`

`$ap = New-SPAuthenticationProvider`

`Set-SPWebApplication -Zone Default -AuthenticationProvider $ap`

The above should do the equivalent of the UI in Central Admin.  Change the Zone to whichever zone you're trying to configure.